# Pig embedded in Java : PigServer in local - no error message but map reduce are not launch (maven ?)

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm trying to run my pig script with PigServer because I need to use "while" and "if" in my script. So java helps with that.

The difficulty is that my main run but nothing happens (except my system.out.print), I don't know why the map reduce is not launch. The program ends without any error.

I think it's a problem with my pom, I think I don't put all of the dependencies needed.

This is my pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.blablabla</groupId>
<artifactId>testPigServer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
        <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

And this is my main :

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pig.ExecType;
import org.apache.pig.PigServer;
import org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException;

public class MainPigServer {
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws ExecException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecException, IOException {

    System.out.println("Hello");
    PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.LOCAL);;
    try {

        String inputFile = "/home/cloudera/jeuxEtudiants/data/parents.csv";
        String outPut = "/home/cloudera/jeuxEtudiants/resultat_PigServer_9";
        queryCSV(pigServer, inputFile, outPut);
        // queryJson(pigServer, inputFile,inputRef, outPut);
    } catch (ExecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        pigServer.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Finally");
    }
}


public static void queryCSV(PigServer pigServer, String inputFile, String outPut) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("dans queryCSV");
    pigServer.registerQuery("donnees_fait = LOAD '" + inputFile + "' USING PigStorage(';') ;");
    pigServer.registerQuery("donnees_group = GROUP donnees_fait by $0 ;");
    pigServer.store("donnees_group", outPut, "PigStorage('|')");
    System.out.println("fin queryCSV");
}

public static void queryJson(PigServer pigServer, String inputFile, String inputRef, String outPut) {
    System.out.println("dans queryJson");
    try {
        pigServer.registerQuery("donnees_fait = LOAD '" + inputFile + "' USING PigStorage(';') AS(id,nom,prenom);");
        pigServer.registerQuery("ligne_finale = FOREACH donnees_fait GENERATE id AS Description, (nom,prenom) AS Test:(nom,prenom);");
        pigServer.store("ligne_finale", outPut, "JsonStorage");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

When I run the main, I obtain :

```
Hello
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.pig.impl.util.PropertiesUtil).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
dans queryCSV
fin queryCSV
Finally
```

I don't know what's happen.

What's more, I try to execute the scripts in grunt, it works.

Thank you for your reading.

Angelik

Comment: I don't think the trouble comes from maven, but from the files you're trying to read. I tested your code and I have the same messages (despite not having the files). You may check that by using PigServer#listPaths

Comment: Side note : I could not compile this code in `MAPREDUCE` mode because of a missing dependency (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3315). Also, I'm having troubles executing the script with grunt in local mode. Could you please tell me if that's the same with you ?

Comment: In Grunt in local ou mapreduce mode, it works (donnees_fait = LOAD '/home/cloudera/jeuxEtudiants/data/etudiants.csv' USING PigStorage(';') ;
donnees_group = GROUP donnees_fait by $0 ;
DUMP donnees_group;). I try to change my inputFile, but it still not work in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find the solution :

In the file settings.xml (you can find it in ???/.m2/settings.xml), you probably have to create one. Put :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>standard-extra-repos</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <!-- Central Repository -->
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <!-- Cloudera Repository -->
                    <id>cloudera</id>
                    <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                   </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

And in the pom :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.businessdecision</groupId>
<artifactId>testPigServer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>cloudera</id>
        <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-cdh4.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jline</groupId>
        <artifactId>jline</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
        <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.0-cdh4.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
        <artifactId>pigunit</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.0-cdh4.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I still don't know what was really the problem but now it works. I probably have more dependencies I need.

Angelik